# Server data change in Single Page Application

Tags: reactjs, redux, .net-core, single-page-application

I am creating a SPA using react-redux and dot net core web api.

I am calling get data in the componentDidMount. I have search functionality as well to implement. So i can do a real time search or search in the redux state that we fetched previously.

Is there any way for the application to be notified about any data changes on the server so that the state data can be up to date?

What is the best approach for such scenario. I need to implement ticketing system as where tickets needs to be updated so that if a ticket is picked up by one user, it should not be visible to other user.

Comment: You can use e.g. websockets to push updates to client applications. But be aware that there is no real safe way to ensure a client has the most up-to-date data due to the nature of distributed systems. That means the client application should be able to deal with errors resulting from stale data. A notification system is just an additional convenience feature to improve usability.

Comment: SignalR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1 is a library that makes the code easier to write, but it assumes you are only running one webserver.